# Reset Password Email with react-redux-firebase

Tags: firebase, authentication, react-native, reset-password, react-redux-firebase

I have a react-native project that is succesfully using react-redux-firebase. The [documentation](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/auth.html) has a resetPassword() method, however it is mapped to Firebase's reset password method. React-redux-firebase seems to be missing a method mapped to Firebase's auth().sendPasswordResetEmail() method.

I am trying to implement "forgot password" functionality and I cannot seem to find the rnFirebase or react-redux-firebase method to send a reset email to a user based on their email address.

Hopefully I'm just missing something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sendPasswordResetEmail` is available under `props.firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail` if within a component wrapped with `firebaseConnect` or `withFirebase`.

Auth methods not available at the top level can be accessed through `props.firebase.auth()` directly [as mentioned in the beginning section of the auth docs](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/auth.html).

Methods exposed at the top level are all involved in dispatching redux actions in some way. If there is some state update or action you would want dispatched at that time it can be done manually (using [exported action types](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/api/constants.html#actiontypes)). If you find yourself doing this, please feel free to open an issue asking for an exposed version of the method that dispatches an action (details in the issue would be awesome).

Disclaimer: I am the main author of [react-redux-firebase](http://react-redux-firebase.com/).